# Don't allow drop down to show full text

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to have the dropdown preview be separate from the actual dropdown text? I have some code like this that I want to only happen on the preview but show the full text when the dropdown is expanded:

```
<option value="">{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit".substring(0,15)+"..."}</option>
```

How do you get the preview in a dropdown to not be the full text and limit with a "..." appending and have that text be fully shown once dropdown is selected

I apologize if this is confusing. Hard to explain what I need. Here's a JS fiddle with what my code looks like to help lessen any confusion.

http://jsfiddle.net/251s9tuf/1/

```css
select {
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<select id='cboSelect'>
  <option value="the_value" label="the text... displayed">the hidden text longer much longer text I want to be shown once dropdown is selected</option>
  <option value="the_value" label="the text displayed2">the hidden text longer much longer text2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to code an element that looks like a select since there is not much you can do with it....

Comment: I would go with a custom solution too, it's tough to do with <select>, you don't have reliable events for open/close.  This fiddle is where I got to before giving up, might give you some ideas.  http://jsfiddle.net/251s9tuf/4/

Comment: Thank you Ireken, that is also what I figured I would have to do but this seems to be more trouble than it's worth just for a few "..."s. It was my supervisors request but I just told her the issue with this stuff and how complex/time consuming it is for something so simple. Hopefully, she understands but I usually never want to resort to the truth since it ruins my reputation occasionally :|

I appreciate the help

Comment: I would just give your supervisor an estimate and let them figure out if it's worth doing.  Happy to implement custom select boxes but it'll take two days!

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS will take care of this for you in Firefox (but Chrome and Safari don't respect this styling on an `<option>`).

```css
select {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<select id='cboSelect'>
  <option value="the_value" label="the text... displayed">the hidden text longer much longer text I want to be shown once dropdown is selected</option>
  <option value="the_value" label="the text displayed2">the hidden text longer much longer text2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: not really what the OP was asking.... and I am not seeing the ... as your code suggests. (Using chrome)

Comment: Oh, you're right. That doesn't work in Chrome. It worked in FF.



Comment: It seems like Chrome respects the _clipping_ of the content, however, it does not add the ellipsis and FWICT this has historically been an issue on `<option>` tags. That said it looks like there will need to be a JS solution to fill the gap or chalk it up to progressive enhancement.